# Exchange 2010: disable some functions for users via powershell

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I am setting up a environment, where not all users should have access to all functions.

Basically, I want some users to only have these functions:

- Personal mail folders
- Personal Contacts
- Personal Calendar
- Outlook Web Access

Which means disabling all of these functions:

- Shared mail folders
- Public folders
- Shared contacts
- Shared calendar
- Shared tasks
- Mobile Notification, Browse, Synchronization

Is there any powershell script that I can run for each user, or a step by step guide to it?

I have been googling for a while, but I really can't find anybody why had the same issue.

I am running Exchange 2010 SP2

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can regulate most of those things by correct use of sharing policies.

Comment: Can you get more in depth with this?